# FileOutputStream close when out of space

Tags: java, ioexception, fileoutputstream, diskspace, bufferedwriter

I've come across a problem using `FileOutputStream` and `BufferedWriter` in Java.

If my disk space is full and I'm trying to write, it will throw `IOException` (which is correct), but when calling the writer.close(), it will fail to close the resource, throwing another `IOException` and keeping the resource opened!

Here is my workaround with `writer.flush()`. It seems to work, but is there a better way to handle this?

```
BufferedWriter writer = null;

    try {
         writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), encoding));
         StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
         writeToStream(buff, separator, data);
         writer.write(buff.toString());
         writer.flush(); // flush before closing to make sure there is enough space on disk to complete the close()
         logger.trace("writeFile: file written, file={}", file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
         logger.error("writeFile: cannot write to file: {}", file, e);
         throw new ... //some exception wrapper here
    } finally {
         if (writer != null) {
               try {
                     writer.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                     // ignore
               }
          }
     }
```

Comment: if write() throws an Exception, then flush() is not executed... so I don't think it is helping...

Comment: If I don't do a .flush() before the .close(), the .close() throws an IOException because it will fail at doing the .flush() (which is called inside the method if not done before). If I do .flush() in the try block, it will throw an IOException (when disk is out of space) and I can call .close() without exception (the BufferedWriter will be already in "flushed mode" and the .close() will work). I'm sure there is a better solution out there. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try and close *all* resources in the reverse order in which you have opened them. Here you try and close only one.

If you have Java 7, use the try-with-resources statement. If you don't, the best way to do that is using [Guava's `Closer`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closer.html) (available since version 14.0):

```
final Closer closer = Closer.create();
final FileOutputStream out;
final OutputStreamWriter writer;
final BufferedWriter buffered;

try {
    out = closer.register(new FileOutputStream(file), encoding));
    writer = closer.register(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
    buffered = closer.register(new BufferedWriter(writer));
    // do stuff
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw closer.rethrow(e);
} finally {
    closer.close();
}
```

If you don't have `Closer`, it is easy enough to recreate.

Comment: I don't understand the point of creating a Closer on a BufferedWriter... You don't need to explicitly close the OutputStream yourself. BufferedWriter closes the underlying writer. I get the same problem with FileOutputWriter alone (without using BufferedWriter), so the problem would be persistent even with the Closer. Thanks